# sms communication between teltonika and server

Tags: c#

My project is **Remote Configuration of teltonika** device fm2200.

I use c# for that. I need to send configuration data as SMS and  save it in the flash memory of the device. I need to do the below given items in my projects.

- How can I configure a **gpsTrackingDevice** using **SMS**?
- Can I send configuration data as SMS to the device?
- Can the the SMS data saved in flash memory?

Comment: Is there any one to help me..

Comment: Hai all..I converted the sms to be sent in hexa format. And send to the device.. SMS is delivered to device.. But it is deleted with the reason that the sms is unknown.. I don't know whether the problem is device or my code??? Is there anyone to help me???